# Unexpected value NaN parsing cy attribute

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dom

Im trying to display the info from my datapoints but i keep getting this error and i cant figure out why. I have searched all over the internet but dont understand the other solutions that are given.
this is an emergency as i need it before 12pm today :(
any help wi=ould be greatly appreciated.

info: user hovers over one dot and info from array appears in infobox! error is for line 22 in the js

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <title>Assignment 3 - web application

    </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>

    <h2 id="ttl">CWD 3500 - ASSIGNMENT 03 - USING FUNCTIONS</h2>
    <div class="infobox" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <h3 class="lName">Book Title</h3>
        <h4 class="dR">Book Author</h4>
        <p>Published in: <strong class="rN">year</strong></p>
        <p>Word count: <strong class="name">published</strong></p>
    </div>
    <svg></svg>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

js

```
window.onload = function () {

    'use strict';

    // dimensions of the svg container 
    const SVG_HEIGHT = 875;
    const SVG_WIDTH = 800;

    // size multiplier
    const SIZE_MULTIPLIER = 1.5;


    var datapoints = [

        {
            value: "A",
            site: "Open to recruitment",
            dR: "Freedman Dr Orit",
            body: "breast",
            rN: "Mueller, Ms Ann",
            name: "(MACRO GENICS) CP-MGAH22-04 / SOPHIA",
            lName: "A Phase 3, Randomized Study of Margetuximab Plus Chemotherapy vs Trastuzumab Plus Chemotherapy in the Treatment of Patients With HER2+ Metastatic Breast Cancer Who Have Received Prior Anti-HER2 Therapies and Require Systemic Treatment",
            date: 3 / 18 / 2016,
            recuted: 3,
            target: 5,
            perc: 60,
            gov: "NCT02492711"

        },
        {
            value: "B",
            site: "Open to recruitment",
            dR: "Shim, Dr Kathy",
            body: "Gastrointestinal",
            rN: " Papaleo, Ms Marianna ",
            name: "(CCTG) CRC.7",
            lName: "A Phase II/III Trial of Neoadjuvant FOLFOX, With Selective Use of Combined Modality Chemoradiation Versus Preoperative Combined Modality Chemoradiation for Locally Advanced Rectal Cancer Patients Undergoing Low Anterior Resection With Total Mesorectal Excision",
            date: 3 / 29 / 2016,
            recuted: 2,
            target: 5,
            perc: 40,
            gov: "NCT01515787"

        },
        {
            value: "C",
            site: "Open to recruitment",
            dR: "Lo, Dr Gregory",
            body: "Genito-Urinary",
            rN: " Cecchetto, Ms Tammy",
            name: "(MERCK) MK-3475-564 / KEYNOTE-564",
            lName: "MK-3475-564 -A Phase III, Randomized, Double-Blind, Placebo-Controlled Clinical Trial of Pembrolizumab (MK-3475) as Monotherapy in the Adjuvant Treatment of Renal Cell Carcinoma Post Nephrectomy (KEYNOTE-564)",
            date: 1 / 11 / 2018,
            recuted: 4,
            target: 5,
            perc: 80,
            gov: "NCT03142334"

        },
        {
            value: "D",
            site: "Open to recruitment",
            dR: "Yeung, Dr Carrie",
            body: "Genito-Urinary",
            rN: " Cooper, Ms Divina",
            name: "(ROCHE) CO39303",
            lName: "A Phase III, randomized, double-build, placebo-controlled, multicenter trial testing Ipatasertib plus  Abiraterone plus Prednisone/Prednisolone, relative to Placebo plus Abiraterone plus Prednisone/Prednisolone in adult male patients with asymptomatic or mildly symptomatic, previously untreated, metastatic castrate-resistant prostate cancer",
            date: 7 / 20 / 2017,
            recuted: 7,
            target: 5,
            perc: 140,
            gov: "NCT03072238"

        },
        {
            value: "E",
            site: "Open to recruitment",
            dR: "Zalewski, Dr Pawel",
            body: "Genito-Urinary",
            rN: "Lauzon, Ms Lynn",
            name: "(BMS) CA018005/CA018005A",
            lName: "A Phase 2, Real-time Assessment of Combination Therapies in Immuno-Oncology Study in Participants With Advanced Renal Cell Carcinoma (FRACTION-RCC)",
            date: 8 / 14 / 2017,
            recuted: 2,
            target: 5,
            perc: 40,
            gov: "NCT02996110"

        },
        {
            value: "F",
            site: "Open to recruitment",
            dR: "Zalewski, Dr Pawel",
            body: "Genito-Urinary",
            rN: "Lauzon, Ms Lynn",
            name: "(ROCHE) WO29636 / IMVIGOR 010",
            lName: "A Phase III, Open-Label, Multicenter, Randomized Study of Atezolizumab (Anti-PD-L1 Antibody) Versus Observation as Adjuvant Therapy in Patients With PD-L1-Selected, High-Risk Muscle-Invasive Bladder Cancer After Cystectomy",
            date: 10 / 20 / 2015,
            recuted: 3,
            target: 5,
            perc: 60,
            gov: "NCT02450331"

        },
        {
            value: "G",
            site: "Open to recruitment",
            dR: "Zalewski, Dr Pawel",
            body: "Genito-Urinary",
            rN: "Lauzon, Ms Lynn",
            name: "(ROCHE) WO30070",
            lName: "A Phase III, Multicenter, Randomized, Placebo-Controlled, Double-Blind Study of Atezolizumab (Anti PD-L1 Antibody) in Combination With Gemcitabine/Carboplatin Versus Gemcitabine/Carboplatin Alone in Patients With Untreated Locally Advanced or Metastatic Urothelial Carcinoma Who Are Ineligible For Cisplatin-Based Therapy [IMvigor130]",
            date: 9 / 5 / 2017,
            recuted: 4,
            target: 6,
            perc: 66.67,
            gov: "NCT02807636"

        },
        {
            value: "H",
            site: "Open to recruitment",
            dR: "Lo, Dr Gregory",
            body: "Lung",
            rN: "Lauzon, Ms Lynn",
            name: "(PHARMAMAR) PM1183-C-003-14 / ATLANTIS",
            lName: "Phase III Randomized Clinical Trial of Lurbinectedin (PM01183)/Doxorubicin (DOX) Versus Cyclophosphamide (CTX), Doxorubicin (DOX) and Vincristine (VCR) (CAV) or Topotecan as Treatment in Patients With Small-Cell Lung Cancer (SCLC) Who Failed One Prior Platinum-containing Line (ATLANTIS Trial)",
            date: 11 / 23 / 2016,
            recuted: 5,
            target: 5,
            perc: 100,
            gov: "NCT02566993"

        },

        {
            value: "I",
            site: "Open to recruitment",
            dR: "Rothenstein, Dr Jeffrey",
            body: "Lung",
            rN: " Mastin, Ms Samantha",
            name: "(ROCHE) BO29554 / BFAST",
            lName: "A Phase II/III Multicenter Study Evaluating the Efficacy and Safety of Multiple Targeted Therapies as Treatments for Patients With Advanced or Metastatic Non-Small Cell Lung Cancer (NSCLC) Harboring Actionable Somatic Mutations Detected in Blood (B-FAST: Blood-First Assay Screening Trial)",
            date: 1 / 19 / 2018,
            recuted: 2,
            target: 5,
            perc: 40,
            gov: "NCT03178552"

        },


        {
            value: "J",
            site: "Open to recruitment",
            dR: "Rothenstein, Dr Jeffrey",
            body: "Lung",
            rN: "Papaleo, Ms Marianna",
            name: "(BMS) CA209-907",
            lName: "An Open-label, Single-arm Phase II Safety Study of Nivolumab in Participants with Advanced or Metastatic Non-small Cell Lung Cancer Who Have Progressed During or After Receiving at Least One Prior Systemic Regimen CA209-907",
            date: 6 / 7 / 2017,
            recuted: 2,
            target: 5,
            perc: 40,
            gov: "NCT03090737"

        },

        {
            value: "K",
            site: "Open to recruitment",
            dR: "Rothenstein, Dr Jeffrey",
            body: "Lung",
            rN: "Papaleo, Ms Marianna",
            name: "(CCTG) BR.31",
            lName: "A Phase III Prospective Double Blind Placebo Controlled Randomized Study of Adjuvant MEDI4736 In Completely Resected Non-Small Cell Lung Cancer",
            date: 1 / 8 / 2015,
            recuted: 2,
            target: 5,
            perc: 40,
            gov: "NCT02273375"

        },
        {
            value: "L",
            site: "Open to recruitment",
            dR: "Koneru, Dr Rama",
            body: "Other",
            rN: "Cecchetto, Ms Tammy",
            name: "(UOT) The 5C Study",
            lName: "Comprehensive Geriatric Assessment and Management for Canadian Elders With Cancer",
            date: 4 / 6 / 2018,
            recuted: 4,
            target: 25,
            perc: 16,
            gov: "TBD"

        },
        {
            value: "M",
            site: "Project site in setup",
            dR: "Rothenstein, Dr Jeffrey",
            body: "Other",
            rN: "Cecchetto, Ms Tammy",
            name: "Study 1",
            lName: "Study 1",
            date: "",
            recuted: 0,
            target: "TBD",
            perc: 0,
            gov: "TDB"

        },
        {
            value: "N",
            site: "Project site in setup",
            dR: "Freedman, Dr Orit",
            body: "Breast",
            rN: "C Mueller, Ms Ann",
            name: "Study 2",
            lName: "Study 2",
            date: "",
            recuted: 0,
            target: "TBD",
            perc: 0,
            gov: "TDB"

        },
        {
            value: "O",
            site: "Project site in setup",
            dR: "Lo, Dr Gregory",
            body: "Genito-Urinary",
            rN: "Lauzon, Ms Lynn",
            name: "Study 3",
            lName: "Study 3",
            date: "",
            recuted: 0,
            target: 6,
            perc: 0,
            gov: "TDB"

        },
        {
            value: "P",
            site: "Project site in setup",
            dR: "Yeung, Dr Carrie",
            body: "Genito-Urinary",
            rN: "Papaleo, Ms Marianna",
            name: "Study 4",
            lName: "Study 4",
            date: "",
            recuted: 0,
            target: 4,
            perc: 0,
            gov: "TDB"

        },
        {
            value: "Q",
            site: "Project site in setup",
            dR: "Zalewski, Dr Pawel",
            body: "Genito-Urinary",
            rN: "Cooper, Ms Divina",
            name: "Study 5",
            lName: "Study 5",
            date: "",
            recuted: 0,
            target: "TBD",
            perc: 0,
            gov: "TDB"

        },
        {
            value: "R",
            site: "Project site in setup",
            dR: "Naassan, Dr Anthony",
            body: "Hematology",
            rN: "C Mastin, Ms Samantha",
            name: "Study 6",
            lName: "Study 6",
            date: "",
            recuted: 0,
            target: "TBD",
            perc: 0,
            gov: "TDB"

        },
        {
            value: "S",
            site: "Project site in setup",
            dR: "Schattner, Dr Ariah",
            body: "Hematology",
            rN: "Mueller, Ms Ann",
            name: "Study 7",
            lName: "Study 7",
            date: "",
            recuted: 0,
            target: 8,
            perc: 0,
            gov: "TDB"

        },
        {
            value: "T",
            site: "Project site in setup",
            dR: "Schattner, Dr Ariah",
            body: "Hematology",
            rN: "Papaleo, Ms Marianna",
            name: "Study 8",
            lName: "Study 8",
            date: "",
            recuted: 0,
            target: 7,
            perc: 0,
            gov: "TDB"

        },
        {
            value: "U",
            site: "Project site in setup",
            dR: "Lo, Dr Gregory",
            body: "Lung",
            rN: "TBD",
            name: "Study 9",
            lName: "Study 9",
            date: "",
            recuted: 0,
            target: 3,
            perc: 0,
            gov: "TDB"

        },
        {
            value: "V",
            site: "Project site in setup",
            dR: "Rothenstein, Dr Jeffrey",
            body: "Lung",
            rN: " Mueller, Ms Ann",
            name: "Study 10",
            lName: "Study 10",
            date: "",
            recuted: 0,
            target: 5,
            perc: 0,
            gov: "TDB"

        },
    ];



    var height = 800,
        width = 800;
    var svg = d3.select("svg").attr('height', height).attr('width', width);

    var max_words = d3.max(datapoints, function (d) {
        return d['name'];
    });
    var x_scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([1800, 2015]).range([0, width]);
    var y_scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 500000]).range([height, 0]);

    svg.selectAll('circle')
        .data(datapoints)
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr('r', 10)
        .attr('cx', function (d) {
            return x_scale(d['published'])
        })
        .attr('cy', function (d) {
            return y_scale(d['name'])
        })
        .on('mouseover', function (d, i) {
            // Select the element by class, use .text to set the content
            d3.select(".infobox .lName").text(d['lName']);
            d3.select(".infobox .dR").text(d['dR']);
            d3.select(".infobox .rN").text(d['rN']);
            d3.select(".infobox .name").text(d['name']);
            // Show the infobox
            d3.select(".infobox").style('visibility', 'visible');
            // make the mouseover'd element
            // bigger and red
            d3.select(this)
                .transition()
                .duration(100)
                .attr('r', 20)
                .attr('fill', '#ff0000');
        })
        .on('mouseout', function (d, i) {
            // Hide the infobox
            d3.select(".infobox").style('visibility', 'hidden');
            // return the mouseover'd element
            // to being smaller and black
            d3.select(this)
                .transition()
                .duration(100)
                .attr('r', 10)
                .attr('fill', '#000000');
        })
};
```

Comment: This will produce a **number**, not a **date** -> `date: 3 / 18 / 2016`. Also, be more exact and accurate where the error occurs, line 22 *as you posted it* is this one: `lName: "A Phase 3 ..........`

Comment: The "name" properties don't contain numbers; they're strings. The "published" properties don't exist at all.

Comment: the error isn't from line 22, you're getting 22 of the same errors

Comment: then how would i go about fixing i looked at the edited version and that doesnt explain anything and half my info i need is lined out

Comment: @SaraFudge Users often edit posts to try and make them clearer, as Pointy has here. It doesn't seem like the code you've provided throws any errors, are you able to provide some more detail about when they appear?

Comment: @ OliverRadini  im not sure what you mean. I am supposed to have 10 dots that appear and when you hover on the dots, the info from the array? i guess then appears in the info box. I have been told i have 22 error but i have no idea on how to fix them. i only get the 1/3 of one cirlcle to appear

Comment: are you able to see an animation that lasts 0.1 second? You use values like `year` and `volume` but none of your data has these values. What if I have a book with 1M copies? What is the use of `maxwords`, and does it has a value?

Comment: @rioV8  i am using another authors code to base off of mine. the data in the 9 or 10 arrays are supposed to display not the books as i have them commented out as use for examples. i want to change the info that displays and i was going along i got these errors so i dont want to continue to add more data in the array in the first bit i have changed isnt working or displaying properly

Comment: Are your date's all dates or are they of a different type? You most likely get a faster working program if you start from scratch and use only the data set, cleaned and consistent. Know what you want to chart and make sure you have the data fields needed and filled with valid values. Start with 1 or 2 data objects.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer really, but I figured I'd post the code as maybe it will help you understand what's wrong. The problem is that the functions

```
.attr('cx', function (d) {
        return x_scale(d['published'])
    })
    .attr('cy', function (d) {
        return y_scale(d['name'])
    })
```

aren't returning numbers. Because `published` isn't defined in your `datapoints` and `name` is a string that can't be coerced to a number. It isn't entirely clear to me what the objective of the code is (meaning what numbers you're intending to use) but by plugging in random numbers in the ranges expected you can at least see the code works...

Hopefully this is of some help to you:

```js
window.onload = function () {

    'use strict';

    // dimensions of the svg container 
    const SVG_HEIGHT = 875;
    const SVG_WIDTH = 800;

    // size multiplier
    const SIZE_MULTIPLIER = 1.5;


    var datapoints = [

        {
            value: "A",
            site: "Open to recruitment",
            dR: "Freedman Dr Orit",
            body: "breast",
            rN: "Mueller, Ms Ann",
            name: "(MACRO GENICS) CP-MGAH22-04 / SOPHIA",
            lName: "A Phase 3, Randomized Study of Margetuximab Plus Chemotherapy vs Trastuzumab Plus Chemotherapy in the Treatment of Patients With HER2+ Metastatic Breast Cancer Who Have Received Prior Anti-HER2 Therapies and Require Systemic Treatment",
            date: 3 / 18 / 2016,
            recuted: 3,
            target: 5,
            perc: 60,
            gov: "NCT02492711"

        },
        {
            value: "B",
            site: "Open to recruitment",
            dR: "Shim, Dr Kathy",
            body: "Gastrointestinal",
            rN: " Papaleo, Ms Marianna ",
            name: "(CCTG) CRC.7",
            lName: "A Phase II/III Trial of Neoadjuvant FOLFOX, With Selective Use of Combined Modality Chemoradiation Versus Preoperative Combined Modality Chemoradiation for Locally Advanced Rectal Cancer Patients Undergoing Low Anterior Resection With Total Mesorectal Excision",
            date: 3 / 29 / 2016,
            recuted: 2,
            target: 5,
            perc: 40,
            gov: "NCT01515787"

        },
        {
            value: "C",
            site: "Open to recruitment",
            dR: "Lo, Dr Gregory",
            body: "Genito-Urinary",
            rN: " Cecchetto, Ms Tammy",
            name: "(MERCK) MK-3475-564 / KEYNOTE-564",
            lName: "MK-3475-564 -A Phase III, Randomized, Double-Blind, Placebo-Controlled Clinical Trial of Pembrolizumab (MK-3475) as Monotherapy in the Adjuvant Treatment of Renal Cell Carcinoma Post Nephrectomy (KEYNOTE-564)",
            date: 1 / 11 / 2018,
            recuted: 4,
            target: 5,
            perc: 80,
            gov: "NCT03142334"

        },
        {
            value: "D",
            site: "Open to recruitment",
            dR: "Yeung, Dr Carrie",
            body: "Genito-Urinary",
            rN: " Cooper, Ms Divina",
            name: "(ROCHE) CO39303",
            lName: "A Phase III, randomized, double-build, placebo-controlled, multicenter trial testing Ipatasertib plus  Abiraterone plus Prednisone/Prednisolone, relative to Placebo plus Abiraterone plus Prednisone/Prednisolone in adult male patients with asymptomatic or mildly symptomatic, previously untreated, metastatic castrate-resistant prostate cancer",
            date: 7 / 20 / 2017,
            recuted: 7,
            target: 5,
            perc: 140,
            gov: "NCT03072238"

        },
        {
            value: "E",
            site: "Open to recruitment",
            dR: "Zalewski, Dr Pawel",
            body: "Genito-Urinary",
            rN: "Lauzon, Ms Lynn",
            name: "(BMS) CA018005/CA018005A",
            lName: "A Phase 2, Real-time Assessment of Combination Therapies in Immuno-Oncology Study in Participants With Advanced Renal Cell Carcinoma (FRACTION-RCC)",
            date: 8 / 14 / 2017,
            recuted: 2,
            target: 5,
            perc: 40,
            gov: "NCT02996110"

        },
        {
            value: "F",
            site: "Open to recruitment",
            dR: "Zalewski, Dr Pawel",
            body: "Genito-Urinary",
            rN: "Lauzon, Ms Lynn",
            name: "(ROCHE) WO29636 / IMVIGOR 010",
            lName: "A Phase III, Open-Label, Multicenter, Randomized Study of Atezolizumab (Anti-PD-L1 Antibody) Versus Observation as Adjuvant Therapy in Patients With PD-L1-Selected, High-Risk Muscle-Invasive Bladder Cancer After Cystectomy",
            date: 10 / 20 / 2015,
            recuted: 3,
            target: 5,
            perc: 60,
            gov: "NCT02450331"

        },
        {
            value: "G",
            site: "Open to recruitment",
            dR: "Zalewski, Dr Pawel",
            body: "Genito-Urinary",
            rN: "Lauzon, Ms Lynn",
            name: "(ROCHE) WO30070",
            lName: "A Phase III, Multicenter, Randomized, Placebo-Controlled, Double-Blind Study of Atezolizumab (Anti PD-L1 Antibody) in Combination With Gemcitabine/Carboplatin Versus Gemcitabine/Carboplatin Alone in Patients With Untreated Locally Advanced or Metastatic Urothelial Carcinoma Who Are Ineligible For Cisplatin-Based Therapy [IMvigor130]",
            date: 9 / 5 / 2017,
            recuted: 4,
            target: 6,
            perc: 66.67,
            gov: "NCT02807636"

        },
        {
            value: "H",
            site: "Open to recruitment",
            dR: "Lo, Dr Gregory",
            body: "Lung",
            rN: "Lauzon, Ms Lynn",
            name: "(PHARMAMAR) PM1183-C-003-14 / ATLANTIS",
            lName: "Phase III Randomized Clinical Trial of Lurbinectedin (PM01183)/Doxorubicin (DOX) Versus Cyclophosphamide (CTX), Doxorubicin (DOX) and Vincristine (VCR) (CAV) or Topotecan as Treatment in Patients With Small-Cell Lung Cancer (SCLC) Who Failed One Prior Platinum-containing Line (ATLANTIS Trial)",
            date: 11 / 23 / 2016,
            recuted: 5,
            target: 5,
            perc: 100,
            gov: "NCT02566993"

        },

        {
            value: "I",
            site: "Open to recruitment",
            dR: "Rothenstein, Dr Jeffrey",
            body: "Lung",
            rN: " Mastin, Ms Samantha",
            name: "(ROCHE) BO29554 / BFAST",
            lName: "A Phase II/III Multicenter Study Evaluating the Efficacy and Safety of Multiple Targeted Therapies as Treatments for Patients With Advanced or Metastatic Non-Small Cell Lung Cancer (NSCLC) Harboring Actionable Somatic Mutations Detected in Blood (B-FAST: Blood-First Assay Screening Trial)",
            date: 1 / 19 / 2018,
            recuted: 2,
            target: 5,
            perc: 40,
            gov: "NCT03178552"

        },


        {
            value: "J",
            site: "Open to recruitment",
            dR: "Rothenstein, Dr Jeffrey",
            body: "Lung",
            rN: "Papaleo, Ms Marianna",
            name: "(BMS) CA209-907",
            lName: "An Open-label, Single-arm Phase II Safety Study of Nivolumab in Participants with Advanced or Metastatic Non-small Cell Lung Cancer Who Have Progressed During or After Receiving at Least One Prior Systemic Regimen CA209-907",
            date: 6 / 7 / 2017,
            recuted: 2,
            target: 5,
            perc: 40,
            gov: "NCT03090737"

        },

        {
            value: "K",
            site: "Open to recruitment",
            dR: "Rothenstein, Dr Jeffrey",
            body: "Lung",
            rN: "Papaleo, Ms Marianna",
            name: "(CCTG) BR.31",
            lName: "A Phase III Prospective Double Blind Placebo Controlled Randomized Study of Adjuvant MEDI4736 In Completely Resected Non-Small Cell Lung Cancer",
            date: 1 / 8 / 2015,
            recuted: 2,
            target: 5,
            perc: 40,
            gov: "NCT02273375"

        },
        {
            value: "L",
            site: "Open to recruitment",
            dR: "Koneru, Dr Rama",
            body: "Other",
            rN: "Cecchetto, Ms Tammy",
            name: "(UOT) The 5C Study",
            lName: "Comprehensive Geriatric Assessment and Management for Canadian Elders With Cancer",
            date: 4 / 6 / 2018,
            recuted: 4,
            target: 25,
            perc: 16,
            gov: "TBD"

        },
        {
            value: "M",
            site: "Project site in setup",
            dR: "Rothenstein, Dr Jeffrey",
            body: "Other",
            rN: "Cecchetto, Ms Tammy",
            name: "Study 1",
            lName: "Study 1",
            date: "",
            recuted: 0,
            target: "TBD",
            perc: 0,
            gov: "TDB"

        },
        {
            value: "N",
            site: "Project site in setup",
            dR: "Freedman, Dr Orit",
            body: "Breast",
            rN: "C Mueller, Ms Ann",
            name: "Study 2",
            lName: "Study 2",
            date: "",
            recuted: 0,
            target: "TBD",
            perc: 0,
            gov: "TDB"

        },
        {
            value: "O",
            site: "Project site in setup",
            dR: "Lo, Dr Gregory",
            body: "Genito-Urinary",
            rN: "Lauzon, Ms Lynn",
            name: "Study 3",
            lName: "Study 3",
            date: "",
            recuted: 0,
            target: 6,
            perc: 0,
            gov: "TDB"

        },
        {
            value: "P",
            site: "Project site in setup",
            dR: "Yeung, Dr Carrie",
            body: "Genito-Urinary",
            rN: "Papaleo, Ms Marianna",
            name: "Study 4",
            lName: "Study 4",
            date: "",
            recuted: 0,
            target: 4,
            perc: 0,
            gov: "TDB"

        },
        {
            value: "Q",
            site: "Project site in setup",
            dR: "Zalewski, Dr Pawel",
            body: "Genito-Urinary",
            rN: "Cooper, Ms Divina",
            name: "Study 5",
            lName: "Study 5",
            date: "",
            recuted: 0,
            target: "TBD",
            perc: 0,
            gov: "TDB"

        },
        {
            value: "R",
            site: "Project site in setup",
            dR: "Naassan, Dr Anthony",
            body: "Hematology",
            rN: "C Mastin, Ms Samantha",
            name: "Study 6",
            lName: "Study 6",
            date: "",
            recuted: 0,
            target: "TBD",
            perc: 0,
            gov: "TDB"

        },
        {
            value: "S",
            site: "Project site in setup",
            dR: "Schattner, Dr Ariah",
            body: "Hematology",
            rN: "Mueller, Ms Ann",
            name: "Study 7",
            lName: "Study 7",
            date: "",
            recuted: 0,
            target: 8,
            perc: 0,
            gov: "TDB"

        },
        {
            value: "T",
            site: "Project site in setup",
            dR: "Schattner, Dr Ariah",
            body: "Hematology",
            rN: "Papaleo, Ms Marianna",
            name: "Study 8",
            lName: "Study 8",
            date: "",
            recuted: 0,
            target: 7,
            perc: 0,
            gov: "TDB"

        },
        {
            value: "U",
            site: "Project site in setup",
            dR: "Lo, Dr Gregory",
            body: "Lung",
            rN: "TBD",
            name: "Study 9",
            lName: "Study 9",
            date: "",
            recuted: 0,
            target: 3,
            perc: 0,
            gov: "TDB"

        },
        {
            value: "V",
            site: "Project site in setup",
            dR: "Rothenstein, Dr Jeffrey",
            body: "Lung",
            rN: " Mueller, Ms Ann",
            name: "Study 10",
            lName: "Study 10",
            date: "",
            recuted: 0,
            target: 5,
            perc: 0,
            gov: "TDB"

        },
    ];



    var height = 800,
        width = 800;
    var svg = d3.select("svg").attr('height', height).attr('width', width);

    var max_words = d3.max(datapoints, function (d) {
        return d['name'];
    });
    var x_scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([1800, 2015]).range([0, width]);
    var y_scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 500000]).range([height, 0]);
    var xoffset = 20, yoffset = 100;
    svg.selectAll('circle')
        .data(datapoints)
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr('r', 10)
        .attr('cx', function (d) {
            return x_scale(1800 + Math.random() * 215);
            //return x_scale(d['published']) <- undefined
        })
        .attr('cy', function (d) {
            return y_scale(Math.random() * 500000);
            //return y_scale(d['name']) <- String
        })
        .on('mouseover', function (d, i) {
            // Select the element by class, use .text to set the content
            d3.select(".infobox .lName").text(d['lName']);
            d3.select(".infobox .dR").text(d['dR']);
            d3.select(".infobox .rN").text(d['rN']);
            d3.select(".infobox .name").text(d['name']);
            // Show the infobox
            d3.select(".infobox").style('visibility', 'visible');
            // make the mouseover'd element
            // bigger and red
            d3.select(this)
                .transition()
                .duration(100)
                .attr('r', 20)
                .attr('fill', '#ff0000');
        })
        .on('mouseout', function (d, i) {
            // Hide the infobox
            d3.select(".infobox").style('visibility', 'hidden');
            // return the mouseover'd element
            // to being smaller and black
            d3.select(this)
                .transition()
                .duration(100)
                .attr('r', 10)
                .attr('fill', '#000000');
        })
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <title>Assignment 3 - web application

    </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>

    <h2 id="ttl">CWD 3500 - ASSIGNMENT 03 - USING FUNCTIONS</h2>
    <div class="infobox" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <h3 class="lName">Book Title</h3>
        <h4 class="dR">Book Author</h4>
        <p>Published in: <strong class="rN">year</strong></p>
        <p>Word count: <strong class="name">published</strong></p>
    </div>
    <svg></svg>
    
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: YES! this is exactly what i wanted! thank you! totally get it!

Comment: how can i now contain the circles in a smaller area?

Comment: @SaraFudge: have you read any of the d3 docs and understand any of the lines of code you have?

Comment: i have been trying too but my teacher is very bad. he gives an example that will only lossely relate to what we are doing and then tell us to figure out a totally different assignment. he does not go over codes with us and instead will tell us to copy an example code from his notes and see how it works for ourselves.